# float right and left with fixed position using css

Tags: html, css

I am having three div. The one on the middle i am having is with **margin:auto** so its displayed in the middle.

Now a div is to be floated on left of the page and one to the right while keeping the middle div in the middle.

Now I can achieve this using the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tny0t6ps/1/)

But I want the position of the both the left and right divs to be fixed with -

```
 position:fixed;
```

which is creating the problem.

Should I have to use a child position:fixed div inside the right and the left floated divs?

Answer (score 2):

element with position:fixed don't respect floating. You can replace your float:left; with `left:0px;` and your float:right with `right:0px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/tny0t6ps/3/

```
.aleft {

    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    padding:5px;
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}

.aright {
   width:100px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px
}
```

Comment: This is fine for the whole page. But not suitable when i want to keep all the three inside a fixed width div.

Comment: Then position the container fixed, and the 3 children inside the container with float ..

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do the height 100% try it auto or add how much px you want i done that

```
   height: auto;
    position:fixed;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tny0t6ps/4/